# How to make a table from a list?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, vba, data-manipulation

I have a set of data in a list form in Excel.

Example list:

```
              Tom       blue
              Jerry     blue
              May       blue
              Tom       red
              Juli      green
              Juli      pink
              Juli      red
              May       red
              Jerry     green
```

I want that the color and the name just come one time and the connection is indicated as a cross so it creates a table like this:

```
        Tom    Jerry      May       Juli     
blue     X       X         X
red      X                 X          X          
green            X                    X
pink                                  X
```

The color and names I can let them appear but I can't figure out how to put the crosses in the right cells. I tried to write it in vba directly and also tried it to do with python with the help of pandas and openpyxl. So both awnsers would work for me.
Also to clarify list contains some 1000 unique vlaues

Comment: Many possibilities, here is one: `df.assign(value='X').pivot_table(index='color', columns='name', values='value', fill_value='')`

Comment: Another: `pd.crosstab(df['color'], df['name'], values='name', aggfunc=lambda x: 'X').fillna('')`